# How to check if array of object exist in state in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, react-hooks, next.js

I'm building a dynamic form using React JS. in one of my form i've created an input form of 10. to get clean code i've created an object and map through it for the form. code is below.

```
{homeAmeneties.map((home) => {
    <div className="h-8 flex justify-end  rounded-md pr-10">
                    <input
                      type="number"
                      onInput={(event) =>
                        (event.target.value = event.target.value.slice(
                          0,
                          event.target.maxLength
                        ))
                      }
                      maxLength="3"
                      onChange={(e) => updateVal(e, home.name)}
                      className="border-[1px] w-1/2  border-black rounded-md h-full focus:outline-none px-2"
                    />
                  </div>
})}
```

then afterwards i've created a `useState([])` and used a conditional to check if the field exists, so that i can only update the value.

```
const [amen, setAmen] = useState([]);
const updateVal = (e, type) => {
amen.some((item) => {
        if (item.name === type) {
          setAmen({ name: type, val: e.target.value });
        } else {
          setAmen({ name: type, val: e.target.value });
        }
      });
}
```

when i run this it throws an error. `amen.some is not a function` error. what i want to achieve is, initially the state is empty. but when one field value changes it add it to the array as `{ name: type, val: e.target.value }`. so before it's added we check if the type already exists. if so then we change the value of that exact array of object. but if the type doesn't exist it create an new object. How can i do that?

Answer (score 1):

I have **`3`** things to point out:

- You said you created an object and `map` through it to render the input fields. Actually, you can only `map` over `arrays` in `JavaScript`.
- In your `updateVal` method call, you are setting the `react state` to an `object` instead of an `array`.
- I wouldn't recommend using `Array.some ()` to update the state. Instead, I would use `Array.findIndex ()`.

### Solution

```js
const updateVal = (e, type) => {
  const updatedAmen = [ ...amen ]; // create a new array to avoid mutating the state directly

  // check if an input already exists with the said type & get the index position
  const exisitingAmenIdx = updatedAmen.findIndex((a) => a.name === type);

  if (exisitingAmenIdx >= 0) {
    updatedAmen[exisitingAmenIdx].val = e.target.value;
  } else {
    updatedAmen.push({
      name: type,
      val: e.target.value
    })

    // finally update the state
    setAmen(updatedAmen)
  }
};
```

Comment: it throws an error `TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'val')`

Comment: @MohammedBekele, there was a typo in the solution. Please try again, I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're setting the state value of `amen` to be the object you're aiming to append to the array:

```js
  setAmen({ name: type, val: e.target.value });

  // amen = { name: type, val: e.target.value }
```

Since it changes from being an `Array`, `Array.some()` is not going to be defined. One way you can go about this is:

```js
  setAmen([{ name: type, val: e.target.value }, ...amen]);
```

Create a new Array so react will update the state. Add the new element, and then use the spread operator `...amen` to extract the other elements.

Comment: Your solution does the update of the array, but it is still giving the same error